# removing spaces from a string in an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, dynamic

I am currently working on a project that reads strings from an input file and stores them into an array.
When it is stored into an Array then I want to remove the spaces so that I can compare the strings in the array with the array stringcards and check if all the Cards from the input file are there.

But I am currently stuck at storing the new strings without the space in the array and printing them out. 
It prints out the first string `REDA`but after that I get an Segmentation Fault.

I would also appreciate it , if someone could give me any hints on how to compare the strings in the cardarray with the constant array and check if all the cards are in the array.

I hope that it's the right approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char * stringcard[] = { "REDA","RED2"
                              "RED3"
                              "RED4"
                              "RED5"
                              "RED6"
                              "RED7"
                              "RED8"
                              "RED9"
                              "RED10"
                              "REDJ"
                              "REDQ"
                              "REDK"
                            };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *reds[13];
    char * cardarray[13];

    int i;

    FILE *file = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    if (file == NULL)
        return 1;
    if(argc!=2) {
        printf("[ERR]");
        return 0;
    }

    for (i =0; i < 13; i++) {

        reds[i] = malloc( 8);
        fgets(reds[i], 8, file);

    }

    int i2 = 0;
    for (i =0; i < 13; i++) {

        printf ("%s", reds[i]);

    }

    for(i= 0; i<13; i++) {
        char *p = strtok (reds[i], " ");


        while (p != NULL)
        {
            cardarray[i2++] = p;
            p = strtok (NULL, " ");
        }
    }

    for (i =0; i < 13; i++) {

        printf ("%s", cardarray[i]);

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Input file:

```
RED A
RED 2
RED 3
RED 4
RED 5
RED 6
RED 7
RED 8
RED 9
RED 10
RED J
RED Q
RED K
```

Comment: Hint: don't use "magic" numbers. It's a very poor and dangerous practice. What is `13`? What is `4 + 1` in `malloc(sizeof(char) * (4 + 1)`? Use constants.

Comment: `13` is the size of the array, `(4+1)` is the maximum string length 4 + null terminator @Jabberwocky

Comment: @xing should it be `reds[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (7 + 1))`?

Comment: @momonosuke yes I know that, but it's a dangerous practice. When the number of your cards changes from 13 to 15 (for whatecver reason) you need to change `13` to `15` all over your code. Use a constant and change the value once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the not needed char. Here you have two functions:

First algorithm is much faster. The second slower but easy to understand

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

---

```
char *removechar(char *str, int ch)
{
    char *cptr = str, *readptr = str;

    while(*readptr)
    {
        if(*readptr == ch)
        {
            readptr++;
        }
        else
        {
            *cptr++ = *readptr++;
        }
    }
    *cptr = 0;
    return str;
}
```

---

```
char *removechar(char *str, int ch)
{
    char *cpos = str;

    while((cpos = strchr(cpos, ch)))
    {
        strcpy(cpos, cpos + 1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 problems:

First: In this loop you increment `i` twice, which leads finally to a buffer overflow.

```
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    char *p = strtok(reds[i], " ");    

    while (p != NULL)
    {
      if (i >= 13)           // debug code
      {                      // debug code
        printf("Bummer\n");  // debug code
        exit(1);             // debug code
      }                      // debug code
      cardarray[i++] = p;
      p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
  }
```

Secondly: you don't allocate enough memory here:

```
reds[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (4 + 1));   // you allocate space for 5 chars
fgets(reds[i], 13, file);                   // and here you tell fgets that
                                            // your buffer has a length of 13 chars...
```

There are most likely more errors though.

Comment: I changed my code , but now I get error stack smashing detected

Comment: stack smashing means most likely that you have an index out of bounds problem. indexes are not checked in C, accessing an array out of bounds yields in undefined behaviour which may (or may not) manifest itself as "stack smashing.". Check your indexes, add debugging code if necessary.